# Sharing content+functionality between two webpages

Tags: plone, zope

I'm currently working on migrating an old webpage (example.se) into an existing plone/zope installation (example.net).
The "new old webpage" which should be integrated should:

- share the same functionality as the existing one
- share parts of the content in both directions, e.g. like papers or collections

example.net currently serving two languages, de and en (example.net/de, example.net/en).
The old webpage only uses english and (currently) no subfolder is used (example.se/)
The domain names should stay as they are to access the webpages.

The solution I'm heading to so far is to create a new seperate instance for the new webapge.
Even if they are seperated, the functionality can be easily shared by using the same buildout scripts.

However sharing content would not be possible, only by copying them over manually (thus, adding new content twice, which should appear on both pages)

Is there a way to archive this?

I'm using plone 4.1.6 and zope 2.13.15.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is not suitable for the Stack Overflow format (see the [FAQ#dontask]). We can help with more practical questions only; if you go with one or the other direction and run into a specific problem, feel free to ask questions about *that*. For this question, perhaps the Plone mailinglists are a better venue?

Comment: I'm about heading into the "seperate instances" direction as redirecting users to another webpage is a no-go and is nearly the same as using two instances. But the question still exists how to share specific content between these instances (as descriped above). However, I can understand that the question does not fit into the SO format pretty well.

Comment: Then edit down your question to focus on that specific issue, perhaps it becomes something that is answerable without opinion having to come into play.

Comment: Edited, hope it now matches the requested SO format. If someone is asking himself why I do not use seperate navigation-roots, take a look at the revisions.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of integration you are trying to achieve here. Linking as related content? Should the other content show up when searching the first site, etc.

Comment: It should appear as *the* content without the visitor is noticing that the content is located at another (web)page (or even the editors). Similar to file sym/hard-links. As stated in the previous rev. there was an egg providing this functionality on an instance-level: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.alias.

Comment: But that is a *totally different* thing altogether, nor does it answer my questions. ;-)

Comment: It sounds as if all you want is for content to appear under the same toplevel domain; Apache rewrite rules can do that kind of thing for you.

Comment: I only want to share parts of the content, and also dynamic, not static using rewrite rules. Using rewrite rules it would not be possible to e.g. build up a dynamic collection on example.se by using a search filter on a folder located at example.net. Additionally it would mess up the whole "root-folder" seperation of the two pages. - Maybe the feature I want to archive is too miss-configured that it should be avoided and thus it is hard to explain :/

Comment: Then you want to share catalog contents, and that's a much harder problem. You should then consider using SOLR to take care of search, for example. This is a *hard* problem, btw.

Comment: Maybe I can explain it more clearly by using the following example: editors of .net and .se are building up their own content. Logical features are shared by the same buildout. Now the .se-editor wants to create a portlet showing the latest conference-papers. They already exist on the .net-instance and the easiest way would to simply set the portlets search-algorithm to this folder. This goes for every other content. That's reuse of already added resources. But they only pick what they need. However, as the instances are seperated, they need to copy all papers and thus distroy the reference.

Comment: I understood you correctly. The solutions are hard.